# expo-camera error “camera not working” on android web app upon toggleswitch camera type

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-camera

I am using expo-camera on my app that can be run to a web on android/ios. Setting camera type works but when I try to switch/toggle camera on android i got an error “camera not working”

Comment: please add more details what do you mean by switch toggle, do you do it programmatically? if yes add a code you use for it.

Comment: @KirillNovikov I just used this...

<Camera type={type}...>
<Button
                  onPress={toggleCamera}
                >
                  <Icon name="refresh" as={MaterialIcons} color="white" />
                </Button>
</Camera>

const toggleCamera = () => {
    setType(
      type === Camera.Constants.Type.back
        ? Camera.Constants.Type.front
        : Camera.Constants.Type.back
    );
  };


initial load is okay but when i try to switch camera it says "camera not working" .. but it only shows on mobile web android